# Add Word docs to Word App without saving to Filesystem

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm trying to create word documents on the fly in VB.NET, and I've found that the documentation on all of this seems very scarce. Right now my program works by looping through a database table, and for each row it pulls out the variables.  The program then loops through and parses a template word doc, replacing variables in that template with variables from the database, then saving as a new doc.

Instead, for every "new doc" that I would be creating, I want to just append it onto another doc, that way when it comes time to parse 1000 rows in the table, I don't have to create and save 1000 different word documents to the filesystem.

I can't seem to find anything out there about this.  Everything mentions merging documents (I actually want to append, not merge) or the only way I can append ("Insert") a document is by using `WordApplication.Selection.InsertFile(newWordDocument.FullName)`. This works, but requires me to save `newWordDocument` to the filesystem before inserting it.

Is there a way to, while still in memory, add `newWordDocument` to my `WordApplication` object?

Here's the pseudocode of what I have now

```
For each row in TableOfVariables
Dim WordApplication as New Word.Application
Dim tempDoc as New Word.Document
tempDoc = WordApplication.Documents.Add
tempDoc = fillVariablesOfTheDocument(tempDoc, row)
tempDoc.Save() 'This is the problem - it saves as a new file rather than appending into WordApplication
Next
```

Comment: I don't think you are doing yourself any favor when treating each page as a separate document which is not want you want in the end. Why don't you create copies of the content and append those to your document (only one!).

Comment: That's basically what I was getting at by having the "docs" be in memory.  "Why don't you create copies of the content and append to your doc" is exactly what I want to do, I just can't see a way to do it.

Comment: Haven't use Word automation much but shouldn't something like `ActiveDocument.Select` `Selection.Copy` `Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToLast` `Selection.Paste` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while, but somehow I found out about `MailMerge`, which I had no idea existed.  Long story short, I can have a template document with variables, and I can have an input excel document.  The excel document will have a header row which contains the variable names, and each individual cell of the excel doc will represent the variable that will go into the document.  When I execute `MailMerge`, the template will be replaced with `n` amount of pages (where `n` is the number of excel rows).  This solves my problem of adding multiple documents to 1 big excel document.  I tested this with 1,000 rows in my excel doc, and it worked flawlessly.

Here's the code I ended up with:

```
        Dim wrdSelection As Word.Selection
        Dim wrdMailMerge As Word.MailMerge
        Dim wrdMergeFields As Word.MailMergeFields

        ' Create an instance of Word  and make it visible.
        wrdAppMailMrg = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wrdAppMailMrg.Visible = True

        ' Add a new document.
        wrdDocMailMrg = wrdAppMailMrg.Documents.Open("Template.docx")
        wrdDocMailMrg.Select()

        wrdSelection = wrdAppMailMrg.Selection()
        wrdMailMerge = wrdDocMailMrg.MailMerge()

        'Open Data Source
        wrdDocMailMrg.MailMerge.OpenDataSource("InputVariables.xlsx", SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]")

        ' Perform mail merge.
        wrdMailMerge.Destination = _
                   Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument
        wrdMailMerge.Execute(False)

        ' Close the original form document.
        wrdDocMailMrg.Saved = True
        wrdDocMailMrg.Close(False)

        ' Release References.
        wrdSelection = Nothing
        wrdMailMerge = Nothing
        wrdMergeFields = Nothing
        wrdDocMailMrg = Nothing
        wrdAppMailMrg = Nothing
```

Now I just have to tweak it to make it run faster and clean up the UI, but the functionality is completely there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make an assignment, just a statement with

> objWordApp.Documents.Add(tempDoc) 'This is where the problem is!

```
 Dim wordApp as new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
 wordApp.Visible = true
 Dim doc as Word.Document
 doc = wordApp.Documents.Add
```

and you don't have to save it until you are good and ready.  This also works

```
 Dim Word As Word.Application
 Dim Doc As Word.Document
 'Start Word and open the document template.
 Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 Word.Visible = True
 Doc = Word.Documents.Add
```

from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383

Comment: GrayFox374, sorry for the misunderstanding, my code actually does have those declarations I just left them out in the question for brevity. My code seems to be working just fine (everything declared properly), I just want to know how to declare a Word.Document in memory and add it to the Word.Application after it has been filled with data

Comment: That's what I was addressing.  objWordApp.Documents.Add(tempDoc) is what you said is the problem, tempDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Add is the solution.  I'm not having any problems populating the doc and adding it to the application, or adding the doc to the app first and then populating it.

Comment: I edited my question significantly to hopefully make it a bit more understandable.